# Ubuntu installation in Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my laptop Acer TravelMate p248-mg, using a USB-Bootable. I selected my USBBootable from the boot manager to load the bootable, then installed it. After installation, Ubuntu says it is complete, and I must restart my laptop. After I restart, why does it always load the MS-windows-10? I am expecting it to first show the GRUB, but it always loads to MS-windows-10.

[image: My BIOS/BOOT]

[image: My Bootmanager]

Comment: Can the people voting to close, please give feedback. What will help this, new, user to improve their question?

Comment: Maybe you explain which option you have used to install ubuntu

Comment: At the end of the process it probably asked you where to install `grub`. What did you answer?

Comment: You might find a simple solution [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/editing-boot-options) or [here](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), although I'd personally make sure to kick Windows' BCD in the nuts and give boot control over to GRUB for the whole drive.

Comment: @roaima it didnt ask sir about where to install the `grub`

Comment: and it always show many `SQUASHFS error: unable to read fragment cache entry` after selecting `try ubuntu without installing` and `install ubuntu` . Is it normal?

Comment: `SQUASHFS error` is unexpected and should not be happening.

Comment: @roaima i download again the ISO file and now im geeting `nouveau 0000:01:0.0 fifo: write fault at 0000100000 engine 04`. you know something about this sir?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert (very old-school, haven't upgraded my PC in years so much has changed), but try disabling the "Secure Boot" option. On my old machine I had to use legacy mode to install GNU/Linux.

Comment: are you using windows 10 sir ?

Comment: Nope. Quit Winblows ages back. I just wondered if the firmware "BIOS" was not automatically deleting the GRUB EFI executable as some OEMs do this kinda low thing for kickbacks and call it "security". Luckily, AFAIK, they must still provide the user an option to disable the feature.

Comment: You may want to try a console during install or a portable Lignux and see if you cannot run "grub-install" and target your HDD/SSD from there as it's then possible to see any error messages that the Ubuntu graphical install won't show.